# why Combobox items are not proportional to the combobox?

Tags: wpf, 3d

[image]

```
  <Viewport2DVisual3D>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
            <Transform3DGroup>

                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="Win1Angle" Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
                <ScaleTransform3D x:Name="ScaleUp" />
                <ScaleTransform3D x:Name="ScaleDown" />

                <TranslateTransform3D x:Name="MoveCenter1" />

            </Transform3DGroup>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>


        <!-- The Geometry, Material, and Visual for the Viewport2DVisual3D -->
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <!-- positions of triangle    0          1           2           3      -->

            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-.78,.58,0  -.78,-.58,0    .78,-.58,0    .78,.58,0"                                
                                    TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" 
                                    TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3" />

        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial  Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

        <Grid x:Name="grdHolder1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="False" Opacity="1" />

    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

I am using 3d in my WPF form. My forms are usercontrols. At runtime, I just create instance of the usercontrol and add to the grdHolder1 in the viewport. But the combobox items are not proportional to the combobox. How to make it proportional?

Anyone!!!! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is that the combobox uses a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) which is basically another window.

> A **Popup** displays its content in its own window on the screen.

I believe that are going to need to apply your transformations to the controls inside the popup window as well as the main combo box.

If you take a look at the [Combo box style page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx)  then it is supposed to have a PART_Popup that you can restyle. However the x:Name definition seems to missing on the popup defintion on that page, so I'd check the style by editing a copy on Expression Blend to make sure it matches.

Extract from [Combo box style page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) 
     ...
     
     ...